# MIPS Assembly Code Giving Break Instruction Executed; No Code Given

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I've been writing this piece of code using MARS:

```html
.data
prompt1: .asciiz  "Enter number of integers in the series:"
prompt2: .asciiz "Enter step value:"
prompt3: .asciiz "The series is:"
prompt4: .asciiz "Summation is:"
prompt5: .asciiz "Standard deviation is:"
prompt6: .asciiz "Do you like to take another try [y/n]"
newline: .asciiz "\n"

.text
la $a0, prompt1
li $v0, 4
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall
move $t2, $v0


la $a0, prompt2
li $v0, 4
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall
move $t3, $v0

for_loop:
beq  $t2, 0, Exit

add $t4, $t4, $t3
add $t5, $t5, $t4

sub $t2, $t2, 1

li $v0, 1
move $a0, $t4
syscall

la $a0, newline
li $v0, 4
syscall

j for_loop

Exit:
li $v0, 1
move $a0, $t5
syscall


la $a0, newline
li $v0, 4
syscall

div $s0, $t5, $t2
```

Over here, I'm supposed to use the *div* function to find the average of the series. Currently, when I use either *div* or *divu* (even while accommodating the mfhi register), I get the following error:

Runtime exception at 0x00400080: break instruction executed; no code given.

I'm not really sure of what I'm doing wrong. Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer,

I was dividing it wrong. If anyone of you have this issue, make sure you are using the right quotient and remainder!